# install nifty-generators on xp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I like django, unfortunately i have to use RoR for 2 projects, and it seems like I'm having problems from the start :P

how to install nifty-generators on xp? i found 3 solutions out there, none works for me :P

1- use `sudo gem install nifty-generators` which won't work obviously

2- `gem 'nifty-generators', '>= 0.4.6`'  .......... the output is

```
Error: while executing gem ...(RuntimeError) 
unknown command nifty-generators,
```

3- `gem "nifty-generators", :group => :development` would give that same error

i'm using rails 3, windows xp pro, 32 bit, sp3, installed ruby on rails using [railsinstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Windows, so I can't advise the first method.

You don't just type 2 and 3 in the terminal, they are to be added to your **Gemfile** in the root of your rails app.  After saving your **Gemfile**, you can run `bundle install` from the terminal to install the gem.  It will then be available for use in your rails app.